# Why does adding a simple route break my Vue app?

Tags: vue.js

I have a reasonably mature Vue 2 app running off a Laravel back end. The route file is fairly standard with a mix of dynamic and static routes. Recently I wanted to add another page to the site so I created the component, imported it into the routes file, and added the route:

```
import Helsinki from "./components/Helsinki.vue";
...
{
        path: "/about-us",
        component: AboutUs,
        name: "about-us"
    },
    {
        path: "/helsinki",
        component: Helsinki,
        name: "helsinki"
    },
...
```

I built the JS and tested on my dev server - no problems at all. However when I push it to my live server, things get weird. Several pages that require pulling data from the backend do not work, throwing console errors saying that response data is undefined. However, other pages that access the same data the same way work fine. The new `Helsinki` component likewise works absolutely fine. If I remove the new route declaration in my routes file, and rebuild, everything is back to working perfectly. I tested running a production build locally in case there was some chunking issue and again, no problem locally.

What might be causing this weirdness?

Comment: It's unknown what causes this. Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Considering this is specific to web server, there could be caching issues or anything else